# Spark: spark.files vs files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the documentation there is `spark.files` with the text:

```
Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. Globs are allowed.
```

Is it the same as the `--files` from the `spark-submit` ?

I tried to use `--conf spark.files` with `#` for renaming but didnt seem that it was working.

Anyone would know ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try with `spark.yarn.dist.files` property

```
val spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()
```

SparkContext is created while **spark** object instantiated. During SparkContext instantiate, `addFile` method is called  if `spark.files` property is configured to add files to be downloaded to all executor nodes.

```
def addFile(path: String, recursive: Boolean): Unit = {
    val uri = new Path(path).toUri
    val schemeCorrectedPath = uri.getScheme match {
  case null | "local" => new File(path).getCanonicalFile.toURI.toString
  case _ => path

}

val hadoopPath = new Path(schemeCorrectedPath)

    ....
 }
```

For example if path value as **localfile.txt#renamed.txt**,  hadoopPath is translated  as  **localfile.txt%23renamed.txt**,  which treat the part after "#" as part of filepath and not as fragment. So it throws FileNotFoundException.

The files specified in `--files, spark.yarn.dist.files` copied into executors node by **deploy** function of Client.scala where fragments are handled properly.